# Does AWS encrypt-at-rest impacts Elasticsearch performance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-elasticsearch

I saved 4.9 million document on AWS Elasticsearch instance. I did a performance test load before and after enabling `encrypt-at-rest`. It turns out that the performance of `encryption at rest` is quit expensive. I did 20 requests per second test load for one minute. The response time was increased from 460ms to 640ms. I can't find any document on AWS talking about encryption performance on Elasticsearch. I wonder whether it is expected performance impact.

Comment: I guess you are using EBS volumes with your ec2 instance. As per docs there should not be any performance difference between encrypted/unencryped volumes althoug it is hard to believe. If we consider it to be truth, the other factor is just your data size. Are you sure that the response times you have mentioned are on the same data size?

Comment: I am not using EC2 instance. I am using AWS Elasticsearch service.

Comment: I understand that but it uses AWS managed EC2 behind the scenes...Anyways what about the data size?

Comment: Right, does encrypt-at-rest using the EBS volumes encryption?

Comment: Yes as I understand it , it simply uses the inherent end encryption. I maybe wrong!